# Saving an excel file in a specific folder

Tags: asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, epplus

Sorry to ask a very basic question, i'm  new to ASP.NET. I just want to know how to save a downloaded excel to a specific folder. Here is my code to download the excel sheet.

```
    public void ExcelForMonthlyReport(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        MonthlyReportExcel excelMonthlyReport = new MonthlyReportExcel();//This class has all excel formating.
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.BinaryWrite(excelMonthlyReport.GenerateMonthlyReport(GeMonthlyUploadData(startDate, endDate)));//method which gives data for excelsheet.
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename = Monthly Report {DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd - HH.mm.ss}.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: May be this link can help you:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312437/how-to-save-excel-file-in-a-specific-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312437/how-to-save-excel-file-in-a-specific-folder)

Comment: Yes I have seen that, which did not help :(

Comment: Have you tried in another browser other than IE like Mozilla ? Please try in these browser

Comment: maybe it helps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174253/7174852)

Comment: If you want to save it on the client pc then forget it. You cannot control that...